# Running Node.js behind Apache, .htaccess configuration together with PHP

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, proxy, behind

I'm working on a project where website content is based on PHP(CodeIgniter) behind Apache server, and my duty is to write a node.js as an API to upcoming mobile version of the app.
(Note, our hosting is managed, we do not have access to virtualhost so using proxypass is out of reach)

I have to make my node file run behind Apache, in a URL like "domainname/api".
When said URL is called, Apache has to bridge this request to localhost:port, where node is living on.

Here is my node.js file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();
var options = {
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       res.send('Hello World!');
});

http.createServer( app).listen(61000, function () {
       console.log('Started!');
});
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ourdomainname\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://ourdomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|info.php|resource|system|user_guide|bootstrap|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|google<somevalues>.html) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/api$ http://127.0.0.1:61000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:61000/$1 [P,L]
```

Although node works locally(on our managed hosting server) (I can call "lynx localhost:61000/" and see proper output), it doesn't work on outside local. All our calls to "ourdomainname.com:61000/api" is sent to CodeIgniter(PHP), not to our node.js file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar issue with running Node.js alongside a wordpress application. Wordpress in the root, and the node app in `www.website.com/api`. Here is a copy of our `.htaccess` file. We struggled with this a lot. What finally worked (thanks to a suggestion on stackoverflow) was to move the `/api` redirect to the top of the file. You also don't need the initial '/' before the directory api.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:51900/$1 [P,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It should be noted that you should add ```RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:51900/$1 [P,L]``` before WP Section to avoid overwitten rule when there is an update to htaccess by WP